# Calling base class member functions with multiple derived classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived-class

OK so I have a polymorphic class hierachy set up like this:

```
class Base 
{
     virtual void show();
};

class DeriveA : Base 
{
     void show();
};

class DeriveB : Base
{
     void show();
};

DeriveA DeriveA_obj;
DeriveB DeriveB_obj;
```

And a pointer type Base

```
Base *bPointer
```

that points to an object type DeriveB Would

```
bPointer->show();
```

call DeriveA_obj.show() and DeriveB_obj.show()?

And if I had a pointer type DeriveA

```
DeriveA *dPointer
```

that points to an object type DeriveA would

```
dPointer->show();
```

call anything other than DeriveA_obj.show(); ? Because it seems like it shouldn't
but I swear it did earlier!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Calling a virtual method calls the most derived version of the method in the object being pointed at.  `bPointer->show()` would call `DeriveA_obj.show()` if `bPointer` points at `DeriveA_obj`, and would call `DeriveB_obj.show()` if `bPointer` points at `DeriveB_obj`.  If you had a `DeriveC` class derived from `DeriveB` and `bPointer` pointed at a `DeriveC` object, then calling `bPointer->show()` would call `DeriveC_obj.show()` if `show()` is overridden in `DeriveC`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a pointer type Base `Base *bPointer` that points to an object type `DeriveB`. Would `bPointer->show();` call `DeriveA_obj.show()` and `DeriveB_obj.show()`?

No, absolutely not. If the `bPointer`'s dynamic type is `DeriveB`, only a call to the corresponding `DeriveB::show` function will be performed. Viceversa, if the dynamic type is `DeriveA`, it will call `DeriveA::show` instead.

> And if I had a pointer `DeriveA *dPointer` that points to an object type `DeriveA` would `dPointer->show();` call anything other than `DeriveA_obj.show();`?

Again, you have to take a look at the dynamic type. The dynamic type is `DeriveA`, which means that `DeriveA::show` will be called.